# Multi Project Play Application Dependency

Tags: java, maven, playframework, sbt

Can I have a play project depending on another play project whose code is kept at different places? ( Not under the same root).

I want to divide my application into something like common-app and business-specific-app where business-specific-app depends on common-app.

Using Play framework in Java.

Saw some examples ( scala), but they have all the code together in different folders but under same root.

Or should I keep common code somewhere as maven project and add that as dependency in business-specific-play-app? What are the best practices?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects